# I was wondering how I would store info['first_name'] into my member class? I would like to create a Member object to store. This is done in Python

Tags: python

```
def get(url, key):
    headers = {"X-API-KEY": key}
    url = "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1" + url
    print(f"Querying {url}...")
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    return data['results']


class Member:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_key = "gCAMVXFNdpPvO0tCX2vEAc8Cyjh8qldeXrUInp0U"
    mem = get(f'/111/senate/members.json', api_key)
    for info in mem[0]['members']:
        print(info['first_name'])
```

I would to store the information from info['first_name'] into a Member class object. But I do not know about how to write it.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the issue is? Are you familiar with the basics of Python?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you absolutely, definitely, should go and read up on classes in Python:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

It's unclear from the question but I interpret this to mean that you want one "member" object per member returned by your query.

```
# Let's start with some fake info rather than relying on your
# function to access remote data
fakeinfo = [{'members':[
    {'first_name':'John','last_name':'Lennon'},
    {'first_name':'Paul','last_name':'McCartney'},
    {'first_name':'George','last_name':'Harrison'},
    {'first_name':'Ringo','last_name':'Starr'}
    ]}]


# **kwargs means that the function can accept an unspecified
# number of arguments with keywords, i.e., 
#   Member(first_name="John")
#   -or-
#   Member(first_name="John", last_name="Lennon")
# You could loop through **kwargs and create the variables
# based on key=value pairs but let's keep it simple for demo purposes
class Member:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        # Assigning a value to self.first_name creates the
        # variable at the class level, so it can be accessed
        # later either within the class or from the outside
        self.first_name = kwargs["first_name"]
        self.last_name = kwargs["last_name"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a list to hold our member objects
    memberlist = [] 
    
    # We're not using the api key or the 'get' function for this example
    #api_key = "gCAMVXFNdpPvO0tCX2vEAc8Cyjh8qldeXrUInp0U"
    #mem = get(f'/111/senate/members.json', api_key)
    
    # Use our fake info for testing
    mem = fakeinfo

    # Loop through our list of members
    for info in mem[0]['members']:
        # Create a new Member object and pass it the required data
        newMember = Member(first_name=info['first_name'], last_name=info["last_name"])

        # Add the new Member object to memberlist
        memberlist.append(newMember)
  
    # To check the output, loop through memberlist and print out the 
    # data we recovered
    for memberentry in memberlist:
        print(f"First Name: {memberentry.first_name}; Last Name: {memberentry.last_name}")
```

The output should be:

```
First Name: John; Last Name: Lennon
First Name: Paul; Last Name: McCartney
First Name: George; Last Name: Harrison
First Name: Ringo; Last Name: Starr
```

It's not a very useful class at this point and I suspect you'll want to read up on both functions and arrays (I think the array type 'dictionary' and 'list' will get a lot of use) to start doing more with it.

Also, note that **kwargs is basically a dictionary. If you're already dealing with a dictionary (such as 'info' in this example) and you're happy to give the class the whole dataset, then you could just pass 'info' as a variable instead of breaking it out into key=value pairs when you create the object.